# High Order Function Constructor

Tags: python, function, generator

I'm programming in Python and I need to program a particular object but I'm having some difficulties: I want an object that can recall on demand a particular generator passed during its construction through init.

Now I've write something like this but obviously it doesn't work.

```
class Foo():
   id = ''

   def __init__ (self, num)
       self.id = num

   def recallGenerator():
       return self.generator
```

where and how have I to pass and store the generator that I want to recall with recallGenerator() ?

Comment: Perhaps if you explained exactly what you are trying to achieve, we could help you. Add examples and expected results if you can.

Comment: I've edited the post as you have suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have solved.

This is the class I wanted

```
class Foo():
    id = ''
    generator = ''

   def __init__ (self, num, gen)
       self.id = num
       self.generator = gen

   def recallGenerator(param1, param2,...):
       return self.generator(param1, param2,...)
```

Now, given a generic generator G(param1, param2...) you can create the object and pass it to the constructor with

```
objectIWanted = Foo(1, G)
```

and then you can recall the generator with

```
objectIWanted.recallGenerator(param1, param2,...)
```

NB note the missing parenthesis when passing G to the constructor.